# Assign Excel Range to a Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, excel, refactoring

I'm working on some code to export a DataTable to Excel, and I'm trying to make it as fast as possible. Right now, I'm looping through each row and each column for each row (nested for loops). When I've got a large DataTable, this process can take some time. Can I assign a range of cells to an array in Javascript instead of looping through the columns?

Here's a sample of what I'm doing.

```
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < json.worksheets.raw.rows.count; rowIndex++) {
    row = rowIndex + 2;
    for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < json.worksheets.raw.rows.values[rowIndex].length; columnIndex++) {
        column = columnIndex + 1
        XLWorksheet.Cells(row, column) = json.worksheets.raw.rows.values[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
}
```

I get the JSON data using an AJAX call to a web service in my ASP.NET project.

Comment: Could you add tags for people to understand, where json.worksheets come from?

Comment: is there a framework that has the object model with json.worksheets object?

Comment: json.worksheets is a property of my json data after doing the eval() call. No framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `XLWorksheet.Range("A1:C100").value = arr`, if `arr` is an array of `VARIANT`.

Comment: I tried setting the value to an array, but Excel put a comma separated list of the values into each cell. Is there a VARIANT array in Javascript?

Comment: Created a dictionary and passed that in as the value. Works! Thanks!

Comment: And exactly what did you do? Assigning a JavaScript Object does not work, nor does a _new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary")_. So what's this dictionary of yours?

Comment: Please, @TimScarborough How did you do that? (Created a dictionary and passed that in as the value)

Comment: @manuell sorry, but I asked this question a decade ago. I don't even remember what project this was on.